# How to get the Git submission information of the current line of the current file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

How to get the Git submission information of the current line of the current file, I want to get the author's username

I have got the current file and the current line number.

```
 @Override
    public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent e) {
        final Editor editor = e.getRequiredData(CommonDataKeys.EDITOR);
        final Document document = editor.getDocument();

        FileDocumentManager fileDocumentManager = FileDocumentManager.getInstance();
        VirtualFile currentFile = fileDocumentManager.getFile(document);


        if (e.getProject() == null || currentFile == null) {
            return;
        }
        final PsiFile psiFile = PsiManager.getInstance(e.getProject()).findFile(currentFile);
        String path = psiFile.getVirtualFile().getPath();
        path = path.replace(e.getProject().getBasePath(), "");
        BookMarkXPersistentStateComponent service = BookMarkXPersistentStateComponent.getInstance();
        String projectName = e.getProject().getName();
        int currentLineNumber = editor.getCaretModel().getLogicalPosition().line;
        service.addBookMark(new BookmarkXItemState(projectName, path, currentLineNumber, new Date()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you are looking for the annotations (blame) info.

If you need this info for a single line only, you could get it directly from git by running a custom git command like `git log -n 1 -L <line-number>,<line-number>:<path-to-file>`. See [git-log help](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--Lltstartgtltendgtltfilegt) for details.

To run this command, use [`GitHandler`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/87ad9d1fa9f28e06d3eaeebc7010ef432790a75f/plugins/git4idea/src/git4idea/commands/GitHandler.java) class.

You could also use builtin Annotations feature of IntelliJ to get this information, however this will require loading annotations of the entire file first. To go this way, check [`com.intellij.openapi.vcs.annotate.AnnotationProvider`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/4999f5293e4307870020f1d0d672a3d35a52f22d/platform/vcs-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/vcs/annotate/AnnotationProvider.java)
After annotating a file via provder you can use [`com.intellij.openapi.vcs.annotate.FileAnnotation.CurrentFileRevisionProvider#getRevision`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/fbd68ca2683d8583a1ac2d8a3a0959770d16a6b8/platform/vcs-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/vcs/annotate/FileAnnotation.java#L257), from which you can get [`com.intellij.openapi.vcs.history.VcsFileRevision#getAuthor`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/dab12fb42ea1fa2cf4e56bc4fe41a6ee4e6394ad/platform/vcs-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/vcs/history/VcsFileRevision.java#L39)

Also, take a look at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004109859--VcsUtil-getVcsFor-return-null

Comment: In diff viewer, How to get the right view revision number?